# Log4J error : Please initialize the log4j system properly

Tags: spring, log4j

I am writing a very basic spring application . While running the application it is giving me an error :

`log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
y.`

I have done a complete fresh setup of eclipse mars and included all the jar files necessary . Is there anything I am missing ? In my referenced library I have also included com.springsource.org.apache.log4j-1.2.15.jar .

Comment: have you included `log4j.properties` in the class path during runtime?

Comment: No i have'nt included . Is it necessary to include the  propert file ? From where do I get this property file ?